# How can I measure the impact of using Math Sans Bold font to get bold titles in Google Search results?

Tags: search-results, title, fonts

While browsing around, realized that you can use bold or some other font for the title to be presented as a search result on Google.

Have anyone tried this yet? Do you know what is the right way to test this in terms of implementation and metrics as indicators?

Here is the example that I've seen recently
[image]

Comment: This seems like a temporary hack to me.   Once Google figures out people are doing this they will probably find a way to prevent it.